# Saved Search "field id" for preferred vendor flag

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have some custom script populating a sublist with all vendor item prices for a given vendor.

I haven't been able to locate the correct field id for the "preferred vendor" flag.

My current search params at present are as follows:

```
var filters = new Array();
            var columns = new Array();
            filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('vendorcost', null, 'greaterthan', 0);
            filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', 'vendor', 'anyof', vendorid );
            columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid');
            columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('entityid', 'vendor');
            columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorcost');
            columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorcode');
            columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorpricecurrency');
            columns[5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('preferredvendor');
            var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('item', null, filters, columns );
```

Unfortunately, column 5 is failing. I've tried 'preferredvendor' with and without a join to 'itemvendor' but without success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preferredvendor` is not a valid searchColumn.

If you are using `Multiple Vendors` feature and you want to search all vendor lines on items along with details that which one is preferred I suggest to use `vendor` and `othervendor` as searchcolumns.

`vendor` will have only `preferredvendor` and `othervendor` will have both preferred and normal vendors.

You can use a condition to distinguish Preferred vendors from others using

```
if(searchResults[i].getValue('vendor') === searchResults[i].getValue('othervendor')){ 
 //this is your preferred vendor search result, and not normal vendor line
}
```

Also, I suggest you to use `othervendor` as filter over `vendor`, if you want to get all vendors(preferred and non-preferred both) in the search results
i.e. Instead of

```
 filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', 'vendor', 'anyof', vendorid );
```

use

```
filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('othervendor', null , 'anyof', vendorid );
```

FYI, there is a filter `ispreferredvendor` but, unfortunately it is not included in search column. But, `vendor` search column as stated above fulfils that requirement

Comment: OK. At least I wasnt going completed nuts. I'll have to compare the main record with the preferred vendor field per line to get a T or F.

Comment: yeah, to avoid loading the whole item record which can be costly in terms of time and usage points, search as stated above can save that efforts